# CSS grid columns changing size with long content

Tags: css, css-grid

I am building a stepper component using a CSS grid.

The grid has two rows and its column count is based on the number of steps in the stepper.

Each step has a header and a body.
Each step header lives in row 1 and takes exactly one column of the grid.

I've made each step header to be as big as its content and to stretch until it reaches the min-width of its siblings.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--steps-count), minmax(100px, auto));
```

The body of each step starts at row 2 and spans the number of columns in the first row, only the body of the selected step is visible, all others are hidden.

THE PROBLEM:
If the step body has short content the grid auto columns are working as expected, but if the body has a huge amount of content like in step 3 in example 1, all the columns in the grid look the same size, it's like the columns no longer respect the **auto** in the **minmax()** function and behave like they are all set to **1fr**.

THE FIX:
The only fix I found is to explicitly set the width of the step body container to match the width of the entire stepper. I really want to avoid that, since the content of the step headers can be changed at runtime.

Example 1 - step with big body content

```css
.stepper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--steps-count), minmax(100px, auto));
  row-gap: 8px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.step {
  display: contents;
}

.step__header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  gap: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.step__body {
  display: none;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column: span var(--steps-count);
  padding: 16px;
}

.step__content {
  display: none;
}

.step__header-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.step__header-title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.step__header-indicator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.step__header-indicator::after {
  content: "";
}

.step--selected {
  color: #fff;
}

.step--selected .step__header {
  background: purple;
}

.step--selected .step__body {
  display: block;
  background: purple;
}

.step--selected .step__content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper" style="--steps-count: 4">
  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 0">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 1">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step step--selected" style="--step-index: 2">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sapien arcu, imperdiet sed augue ut, rhoncus elementum urna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut id ultricies libero, ac interdum
          justo. Donec auctor quam in neque commodo, eget auctor turpis condimentum. Integer blandit urna vitae nisi bibendum luctus. Ut a laoreet purus, vel dictum nibh. Vestibulum non faucibus mi, eu tempor lectus. Mauris in varius lacus. Nullam pretium
          at felis nec pharetra. Suspendisse dui ex, ullamcorper ac scelerisque ut, fermentum at urna. Aliquam efficitur, leo et egestas convallis, sapien tortor tincidunt velit, a faucibus ligula dui ac eros. Nunc sed sagittis orci. Fusce quam est, convallis
          ac commodo eget, tincidunt non erat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 3">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example 2 - step with small body content

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.stepper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--steps-count), minmax(100px, auto));
  row-gap: 8px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.step {
  display: contents;
}

.step__header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  gap: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.step__body {
  display: none;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column: span var(--steps-count);
  padding: 16px;
}

.step__content {
  display: none;
}

.step__header-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.step__header-title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.step__header-indicator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.step__header-indicator::after {
  content: "";
}

.step--selected {
  color: #fff;
}

.step--selected .step__header {
  background: purple;
}

.step--selected .step__body {
  display: block;
  background: purple;
}

.step--selected .step__content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper" style="--steps-count: 4">
  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 0">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 1">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step step--selected" style="--step-index: 2">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">
        <div>step 3 short content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 3">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MichaelBenjamin said, it's related to the content of the body. When it exceed a certain size the calculation of the column size behave differently.

I will try to grab the detail of such calculation but a solution is to make sure the body doesn't contribute to the grid size calculation by using `width:0;min-width:100%;`

```css
.stepper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--steps-count), minmax(100px, auto));
  row-gap: 8px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.step {
  display: contents;
}

.step__header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  gap: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.step__body {
  display: none;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column: span var(--steps-count);
  padding: 16px;
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.step__content {
  display: none;
}

.step__header-text {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.step__header-title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.step__header-indicator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.step__header-indicator::after {
  content: "";
}

.step--selected {
  color: #fff;
}

.step--selected .step__header {
  background: purple;
}

.step--selected .step__body {
  display: block;
  background: purple;
}

.step--selected .step__content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stepper" style="--steps-count: 4">
  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 0">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 1">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step step--selected" style="--step-index: 2">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sapien arcu, imperdiet sed augue ut, rhoncus elementum urna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut id ultricies libero, ac interdum
          justo. Donec auctor quam in neque commodo, eget auctor turpis condimentum. Integer blandit urna vitae nisi bibendum luctus. Ut a laoreet purus, vel dictum nibh. Vestibulum non faucibus mi, eu tempor lectus. Mauris in varius lacus. Nullam pretium
          at felis nec pharetra. Suspendisse dui ex, ullamcorper ac scelerisque ut, fermentum at urna. Aliquam efficitur, leo et egestas convallis, sapien tortor tincidunt velit, a faucibus ligula dui ac eros. Nunc sed sagittis orci. Fusce quam est, convallis
          ac commodo eget, tincidunt non erat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step" style="--step-index: 3">
    <div class="step__header-wrapper">
      <div class="step__header">
        <div class="step__header-indicator"></div>
        <div class="step__header-text">
          <div class="step__header-title">Step 4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step__body">
      <div class="step__content">Step body 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`width:0` will disable the size contribution and `min-width:100%` will make sure that your content fill all the available space (defined by the other content)

Comment: I was trying to find a solution for a couple of days.  Thank you and  @Michael Benjamin so much!

Answer (score 2):

Few observations:

1. The columns break when the body content *wraps*. It's not just "a huge amount content" causing the problem, it's the wrap.

   The body of the stepper preserves the column width until the moment the content wraps. The columns then *start* shrinking, and continue to shrink as more content is added, until the columns reach equal width.

   Like you said, they *"behave like they are all set to `1fr`"*.
2. The problem is the `auto` value in the `minmax` argument in `grid-template-columns`. For some reason (I don't have time to look into this at the moment), the `auto` value resizes the columns on wrap.
3. Perhaps switch from `auto` to `min-content`.

(I'll ping @TemaniAfif. Maybe he can help.)